# Docker using of MySQL password null

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, symfony, local

I am running my docker images correctly in my Symfony project on Windows.

I set up MySQL environment variables that I used before with WAMP but SQLyog throws:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@172.18.0.1 (using password: NO)
```

My docker config yml in project looks:

```
    version: '3'

services:
  project_web:
      container_name:  project_web
      build: ./scripts/provision/docker/nginx/
      depends_on:
        - " project_php"
      ports:
          - 8080:80
      volumes:
          - .:/var/www/html:cached
   project_php:
      container_name:  project_php
      build: ./scripts/provision/docker/php-fpm/
      depends_on:
        - "prosper_mysql"
      expose:
          - 9000
      volumes:
          - .:/var/www/html:cached
   project_mysql:
      container_name:  project_mysql
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
          - ./scripts/provision/docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql:cached
          - .:/var/www/html:cached
      ports:
          - 3306:3306
      environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
         MYSQL_DATABASE:  project_db
         MYSQL_USER: root
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: null
```

Comment: It's not `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1` but `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1` or `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes`.

Comment: It throws an error  "mapping values are not allowed here
  in ".\docker-compose.yml" @StefanGolubović

Comment: Sorry, it's `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1` or `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes` (based on other env vars in compose).

Answer (score 1):

The following formats work:
`MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes`, `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1`, `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true`

Comment: Incorrect. You'd get the following error on using "true" as the value.
`services.phpmyadmin.environment.MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD contains true, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null`

Comment: I use `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1`, and it works ok.